# cocos2d whirl integration: touch area blocked by banner

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, touch, iad

when i integrate whirl with cocos2d (landscape), i set the admob banner on top screen: 
here is my part of my -(void)adjustAdSize:

```
newFrame.size.width = screenSize.width;
newFrame.origin.x = (self.adView.bounds.size.width - adSize.width)/2;
newFrame.origin.y = 0;
adView.frame = newFrame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

when the connection is fine, the app will pop out at the bottom, then slide up to the top (as indicated newFrame.origin.y = 0)
but when the connection is slow, the banner didn't show up. however, the bottom area can not sense my touch, until the banner shows up and slide to the top.

I use the source code from http://emeene.com/2010/10/adwhirl-cocos2d-iphone/
is there any way to deal with it? or just let the banner appear on the top directly. (i use the same code for my iPad version, where the banner is on bottom, the banner just directly shows there. so i works perfectly well)

please help me!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the animation part and place the adView directly to the position where you want it to be. Something like this:

```
newFrame.size.width = screenSize.width;
newFrame.origin.x = (self.adView.bounds.size.width - adSize.width)/2;
newFrame.origin.y = 25;
adView.frame = newFrame;
```

You will want to remove the lines with UIView beginAnimation and commitAnimation and tweak the frame origin to move the banner to where you want it to be.

Comment: you mean remove the first 2 lines and the last line of his method? plz check out the original (-(void)adjustAdSize:). there is no beginAnimation in the method

Comment: If there wasn't a beginAnimation then the whole animation won't work in the first place. I just assumed you didn't post the entire code. If you don't mind downloading Kobold2D (http://www.kobold2d.com) you could have a look at the fadeIn/fadeOut methods of the KKAdBanner class to understand how this slide in/out animation is done. KKAdBanner displays iAd and AdMob banner views.

Comment: i gave you the link. the only thing i did is downloading adwhirl sdk and admob sdk. then do as it requires. but i still can't find it (don't even know where they set the start location at the bottom)

Comment: could you have a look at the tutorial link? it's really short.

Comment: sry, it does have beginAnimations. but after removing it, it is still the same.

Comment: the thing is, the animation did pop out on top directly now. but before it shows, the bottom area is still not touchable. until the banner shows. if no connection, then the bottom area is always not touchable

Comment: wow. I dig into your code. and totally understand now!!! awesome! is it your another project?

Comment: Kobold2D is a game engine I'm building on top of Cocos2D together with other relevant libraries (cocos2d-iphone-extensions, cocos3d, Lua and so on).